# Custom HTML element attribute not showing - Web-Components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I'm exploring web-components custom HTML elements, and I am running into a problem adding custom attributes to my custom elements: any value I set in the markup is never honored.
For a simple element like this, which should show the text supplied in the "flagtext" attribute, it does always show the default value.

```
<test-flag flagtext="my text"></test-flag>
```

Full JSBin sample is [here](http://jsbin.com/vepizulefi/1/edit?html,js,output).

The JSBin uses the Polymer library (as this is the only thing I can pull in there). I am using webcomponents.js generally, same result. Both in Chrome 49 and in Firefox 45 gives same result. There is no error showing in the console or debugger.

Every sample I find on the web has similar code but I tried various versions and it always refuses to update. I even copied a few samples into JSBin and they do not work either.

What could be wrong? I understand it is experimental technology but the consistency with which this isn't working is still surprising. Has this standard been abandoned? (I see that the latest April 2016 W3C draft of custom elements has entirely changed its approach.)

When I define "attributeChangedCallback" function, it does not fire.
I can easily modify the property via Javascript, this is not a problem.

But why can I not specify the property in markup, as I am supposed to?

**Edit - full code**

Note that you'll need to put these into separate files for the HTML import, and that you need the "webcomponents-lite.js" library.

**Main HTML file**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
        test-flag
        {
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="lib/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="test-flag.html">

  Here is the custom test-flag component: 
  <p>      
  <test-flag flagtext="my text"></test-flag>  
</body>
</html>
```

**File: test-flag.html**

```
<template>

    <style>
    </style>

    Content:
    <div id="testflagID">
    </div>

</template>


<script>    

    (function() {

        var _currentScript = (document._currentScript || document.currentScript);
        var importDoc = _currentScript.ownerDocument;
        var customPrototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);        
        Object.defineProperty(customPrototype, 'flagtext', {value: '(default)', writable: true});       
        document.registerElement('test-flag', {prototype: customPrototype});


        customPrototype.createdCallback = function() 
        {
            var template = importDoc.querySelector('template');
            var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
            var idx = clone.querySelector("#testflagID");
            idx.textContent = this.flagtext;
            var root = this;
            var createdElement = root.appendChild(clone);

        };

    })();

</script>
```

Comment: WebComponents are Chrome-only. It doesn't work in all browsers except Chrome and Opera (opera have the same engine than chrome). http://caniuse.com/#search=components . Avoid to use it

Comment: (a)This isn't correct - the webcomponents.js polyfill enables the functionality in many browsers, and in my tests much of it works - but not this, (b) as mentioned above, the sample isn't working in Chrome either

Comment: `enables the functionality` is wrong. Emulates the behaviour, but that's not web components. However, I can't access jsbin.com from my work, it's because is better that you share the code **in the question itself** (as the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) said).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 concepts that are not automatically linked together.

In the HTML code:

```
<test-flag flagtext="my text"></test-flag>
```

...term `flagtext` **is an HTML attribute** (not a *property*).

In the JavaScript code:

```
Object.defineProperty(customPrototype, 'flagtext', {value: '(default)', writable: true})
```

...term `flagtext` **is a JavaScript property** (not an *attribute*).

For standard elements, the browser automatically binds the *property* value to the *attribute* value (and vice versa). For Custom Elements, too (with standard *attributes*). But if you want to add a custom *attribute*, you'll have to bind it manually.

For example, in the `createdCallback()` method, add:

```
this.flagtext = this.getAttribute( 'flagtext' ) || '(default)'
```

---

**Live sample:**

```js
document.registerElement( 'test-flag' , {
  prototype: Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype, {
    flagtext: {
      value: '(default)',
      writable: true
    },
    createdCallback: {
      value: function() 
      {
        this.flagtext = this.getAttribute( 'flagtext' ) || this.flagtext
        this.innerHTML = 'flagtext=' + this.flagtext
      }
    },
  } )
} )
```

```html
<test-flag flagtext='new content'>Hello</test-flag>
```

NB: the `attributeChangedCallback()` method is fired only when an *attribute* is changed **after** element creation (which is not the case here).

Comment: @Supersharp I wish I had found this a month ago. I was searching my b... off about how properties and attributes are related and why I they were in some cases bound and in some cases they weren't.

I wish this had been made more clear by all those blogs and sites promoting web components.

Awesome, even though I've arrived quite late. Thanks a L-O-T